# How do you show in a diagram of a (DIN) connector that you are looking from the front or from the back?

Tags: connector, diagram, schematic, din

Exploring the many wiring diagrams of DIN connectors on the internet (an example shown in the image below), I note that the more detailed authors always emphasize whether one is looking at these connectors from the front (i.e. looking directly at the pins) or from the back (basically looking over the cable). Obviously this matters as the image is essentially mirrored depending on this perspective.

[image]

Is there a commonly accepted way how to indicate this in the diagram or is their a common practice in the field that dictates how such diagrams should be interpreted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience nothing is clearer than a verbal description such as ‘looking into the front of a female connector’.  The pin numbering is also helpful if it’s marked on the connector itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, and it's bitten me many times.  *In general*, I've found that if the document (like a user manual) assumes you are a *user* of the system of which the connector is a part, then you will be shown the plug from the mating side.  If the document (like a part datasheet) assumes you are an *assembler* of the system of which the connector is a part, then you will be shown the plug from the wire entry side.  This becomes very confusing when imprecise terms like "view into the plug" or "connection side" are thrown about or when the drawing is for the mating connector and they expect you to flip it around in your head.

The foolproof methods I've used are (not all will be possible for you):

- Use connectors with marked locations or a "Pin 1" marking.
- Use connectors with asymmetric pin layouts.
- Use precise language such as "mating side".
- Include a pin map on a perspective-view or otherwise unambiguous drawing.

Answer (score 1):

While not a complete answer to the question, many vendors of circular connectors like MIL-38999 (Amphenol, for example) use the "looking into the mating side, or front" of the connector way.  This is irrespective whether the connector is male or female, and whether or not the connector is chassis mounter (a jack) or cable mounted (a plug).

Here's a example from the Amphenol catalog.

[image: 9 pin circular connector]

And is says on that page "front face of pin inserts illustrated".

This means the pin numbers will be mirrored between the chassis and cable connectors of a given mating pair.  In the picture above, that means that the pin numbers will increment going CCW around the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Catalog for D38999 21-35 shown on page 9 of 183 "Front face of pin inserts illustrated".  I have a pic verifying this part I took a pic of showing the "rear", insert side where the contacts will be inserted from, is indeed depicted accordingly in the graphic in the catalog.  The ridges in the pic are where the contacts are inserted (install, load, etc..), and for the front mating face you can see the keying.

Ok, wow,,, pain in the but to add pics and label accordingly..  This part is for contacts of the type socket. Soo top pic is lateral view, showing top side of pic the ridged "rear" contact insert end with thread,,, while the bottom shows the receptacle mating face (to plug) with the keys..  Next pic with red is the actual ridged contact insert view/face (rear).  The last pic, black is mating face "front".  Hope this helps.  Glad when I got the parts in so that I could verify accordingly.

[Amphenol D38999 Catalog](https://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/resources/literature/view/38999-catalog%5D)
[[image: lat view][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZFwK.png)
[image: insert view (rear)]
[image: "front" mating face view]